Most simple software to subscribe to all folders of an IMAP account (Linux / Windows)?
I am in the search of a software that allows me to subscribe an IMAP user to all folders that are accessible in a certain account.
I am aware that this usually is not needed because some MUAs provide the option to display all folders in their UI regardless of to which folders the user is subscribed. Unfortunately, in my case, I can't use that feature (the reason is complicated and not worth explaining here).
So I'd like to know if there is a software tool for Windows or Linux, ideally for the command line, that lets me subscribe a user to all folders in an IMAP account. I really don't need anything more, and ideally, the tool should provide only options that are needed for that specific purpose, or at least shouldn't force me to learn about other fancy options.

Sounds to me not as you want to "subscribe" to all IMAP folders, but use IMAP idle on all folders to receive updates. To my knowledge "subscribe" in IMAP context simply means display the folder in mail program and periodically check it for new messages. There is no real subscription mechanism to receive notifications on new messages. See also https://superuser.com/questions/61585/what-does-it-mean-to-subscribe-to-an-imap-folder and https://stackoverflow.com/q/22014353/150978

Thank for your comment, and +1. However, I really want to subscribe to every folder. It is really not about receiving updates. It is just about viewing the folders, and hence, about subscribing.
